# Range.End with blanks VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a dynamic range that will bring back all results from a fixed set of cells, unfortunately I'm having trouble with the `Range.End` method since there are blanks in between. For Example there may be no values in `A8:A10` but it may start on `A11` and that row will have data in it. All the tables will be different but it's fixed to the cell range below.

I also saw `Range.Find` but I could not get that to work either.

The cell range is: `A8:F18`

```
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & lastRow).Formula = _
    Source.Worksheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("A8").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & lastRow).Formula = _
    Source.Worksheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("D8").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastRow).Formula = _
    Source.Worksheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("B4").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & lastRow).Formula = _
    Source.Worksheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F8").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & lastRow).Formula = _
    Source.Worksheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("E8").Value
```

---

```
       A     B     C       D        E         F           
10  vendor1 ACH vendor1  500.00     XXX 0118-CLIENT-XLIVES
11  vendor2 ACH vendor2  600.00     XX  0118-CLIENT-XLIVES
12  vendor3 ACH vendor3  400.00     XX  0118-CLIENT-XLIVES
13  vendor4 ACH vendor4  $900.00    XXX  0118-CLIENT-XLIVES
14  vendor5 ACH vendor5  $6,000.00   0118-CLIENT-XLIVES
15  vendor6 ACH vendor6  $800.00         0118-CLIENT-XLIVES
16  vendor7 ACH vendor7  $88,000.00      0118-CLIENT-XLIVES
```

Comment: so you want to find the last cell with data in the range `A8:F18` where there could be any amount of blank rows between A8 and F18?

Comment: Your question is not clear; I understand that you want to copy the values located in the "SUMMARY DATA SHEET", cells A8, D8, B4, F8, and E8; and paste those values in "Sheet2", in the first empty row in columns B, D, A, E, and C. If I am wrong, please clarify your question.

Comment: @GMalc I used A8, D8, F8, and E8 as the first row in the range. Essentially I want it to pick up all non blank values in the range A8:F18. The other reference is a single cell value that will be the same for each line item, B4. To reiterate the example, I might have values that start on row 10 and may finish on row 15, but since that range is fixed, I will still need the code to search rows 8-18 and return all non blanks.

Comment: Still unclear; Do you want any cell in 'Range("A8:F18")' that contains data, to be copied, then pasted to "Sheet2" on the first empty row? How do you want the copied data from `Range("A8:F18")` pasted to "Sheet2"? Your example shows that you want data from specific cells from `Range("A8:F18")`  to be pasted to specific cells in "Sheet2",  Do you want to copy specific data and paste in specific cells in "Sheet2"? or  paste all the copied values in the first empty row?   You can accomplish your task using a FOR/IF loop, but need to know what you want to do with your copied data..

Comment: @GMalc I added a sample of the range above that is in rows 10 thru 16. I have formulas in the whole range A8:F18, but there may not be data pulled into those cells based on formula conditions. Also for insistence, column B will not get pulled, thats why I want it go through all of column A (A8:A18) and pull all non blanks then Column D (D8:D18) and paste in ("Sheet2") and so on. So in the specific example above I would want the code to return all the values from A10:A16, D10:D16, etc but I still need it to search all rows 8-18 for each column since I may have different results on other Wrkshts

Comment: Still unclear what you are doing when pasting the data to sheet2. I would suggest that you copy the range A8:F18 and paste to sheet2 as values. Then delete empty cells.

Comment: @GMalc I don't need to copy everything in the range A8:F18 only specific columns, A,D,E,F. The problem is I have about 60 of these worksheets so I can't afford to delete empty cells. I wont use Columns B or C.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to find the first row with data in the `Range("A8:A18")`, if that assumption is correct, then this is an example:

```
Sub foo()
Dim Source As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim targetLastRow As Long, sourceFirstRow As Long
Set Source = ThisWorkbook ' ### MODIFY AS NEEDED

Set wsSource = Source.Worksheets("Sheet1") '#Source.Worksheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET")
Set sourceRange = wsSource.Range("A8:A18")
sourceFirstRow = sourceRange.Find("*", After:=wsSource.Range("A8")).Row

Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
targetLastRow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

wsTarget.Range("B" & targetLastRow).Value = _
    wsSource.Range("A" & sourceFirstRow).Value

wsTarget.Range("D" & targetLastRow).Value = _
    wsSource.Range("D" & sourceFirstRow).Value

' etc...

End Sub
```

If you want to transfer the values from all cells in rows 8-18 that have data, also assuming that every row *after* the first row has data, then I think you just need to modify `sourceRange` and make some change to the target using `Resize`:

```
Sub foo()
Dim Source As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim targetLastRow As Long, sourceFirstRow As Long
Set Source = ThisWorkbook ' ### MODIFY AS NEEDED

Set wsSource = Source.Worksheets("Sheet1") '#Source.Worksheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET")
Set sourceRange = wsSource.Range("A8:A18")
sourceFirstRow = sourceRange.Find("*", After:=wsSource.Range("A8")).Row
Set sourceRange = wsSource.Range("A" & sourceFirstRow & ":A18")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
targetLastRow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

wsTarget.Range("B" & targetLastRow).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, 1).Value = _
    sourceRange.Value

wsTarget.Range("D" & targetLastRow).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, 1).Value = _
    sourceRange.Offset(, 3).Value

'etc...
End Sub
```